# ProGuard does Not Allow My Signed APK to run

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

I searched heavily about this on google,stackoverflow etc but didn't got a perfect solution yet. Actually I want to prevent my application from getting reverse engineered, to achieve this I'd used proguard and defined some set of rules to my project. After defining above set of rules my signed apk does not goes beyond Splash Screen. If there are some other solutions other than Proguard those are also welcome.

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep public class com.bbpos.emvswipe.* {
 public *** get*();
 public void set*(***);
}


-keep public class com.bbpos.wisepad.* {
 public *** get*();
  public void set*(***);
}

-dontwarn com.bbpos.**

-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.realm.**

-keep public class * extends org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.**

-keep public class                                                                  com.google.android.gms.cast.
framework.media.TracksChooserDialogFragment
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.**

-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zznv

-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**

-keep class okhttp3.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

-keep class java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*

-keep class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

-keep public class org.simpleframework.**{ *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.**{ *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.core.**{ *; }
-keep class org.simpleframework.xml.util.**{ *; }
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.**
```

logcat

```
W/dalvikvm: Failed processing annotation value
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: APP_PREFERENCE
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:209)
W/System.err:     at cbm.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at cbk.i(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.sparken.echallan.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at com.sparken.echallan.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
```

Comment: `defined some set of rules to my project` -> it's hard to see what files are affected without going through the codebase. My first suggestion is disable all the custom rules you have added & add only standard proguard rules for each library specified in their github page and check the resulting build. After that proceed with further customization.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing all public word occurences from your progaurd-rules file.